# Web service Axis2 client code generation issue

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, axis, webservice-client

I'm trying the consume a web services built using Axis2, so I have followed [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/axis2/axis2-client.shtml) for creating client code.

I have the endpoint and I'm able to access it through the browser. But trying to generate the client code with:

```
WSDL2Java.bat -uri <<endpoint>> -o client
```

throws the exception below:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
>               at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:181)
>               at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
>               at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
>               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>               at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
>               at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
>               at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
>               at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
>               at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
>               at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
>               at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:272)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
>               at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
>               at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:99)
>               ... 2 more

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the WSDL from a browser but not from the tool in command line then it's possible that your browser uses a HTTP proxy for it's connection while wsdl2java goes straight for the address.

Try setting some JVM parameters for using a proxy, as described in [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) and if that fails, there is always the option to download the WSDL with the browser and run wsdl2java with the locally downloaded file.